# How to download universal artifacts from the artifacts UI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

It seems like every other package in artifacts can be downloaded from the UI as a zip except universal artifacts. Why is that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Currently, you must use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) to download the Universal Package. Azure DevOps doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to download the package.

```
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam --feed FabrikamFiber --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --path .
```

I've noticed there is already a similar feature suggestion in the following link, you can vote it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/495533/download-universal-package-trough-api.html

More details please refer to the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#download-a-universal-package